# Write a command to switch to specific directories

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have some directories that I have to go to a lot more often than others, like for music, work, programming, etc. So I want to have exclusive commands, say "gotomusic" or "gotodropbox" to go to these folders because otherwise I have to type something like `cd /media/sda9/Work/Dropbox` and so on.

Is it a good idea? Is there a better way of getting the same result?

I tried writing the following script "gotomusic"

`#!/bin/bash`

`cd /media/sda8/Music`

But it does not work. What is wrong in doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can find the right solution on stackoverflow:

[change-current-directory-from-a-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script)

Answer (score 1):

You may do this by using aliases, just add in your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias gotomusic='cd /home/user/music'
alias gotopics='cd /home/user/pictures'
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you can't change the working directory of the parent process.

Related to your problem the procedure is as follows:

The current working directory of your interactive shell is `$PWD`. Then you start `gotomusic` and your interactive shell (i will call it `parentbash`) starts a new instance of `bash` (i call it `childbash`) as a new process. `childbash` inherits several attributes of `parentbash`. Among other things it inherits it's working directory from `parentbash`.

Since you instruct `childbash` to read the commands from your script it changes its own working directory to `/media/sda8/Music` and terminates.

At this point `parentbash` gets active again with the same state as before the execution of `childbash`.

In order that `parentbash` should invoke its `cd` builtin command you should source your script. This is easily done by

```
source gotomusic
```

But the question remains if this approach is well suited for a quick directory change.

There are several implementations of directory-bookmark systems `bashmarks` but i think the best solution would be that you can easily choose from a list of the most used directories. I don't know whether there exists something like this for `bash` but if you want to use `zsh` you can get it at [[1](https://github.com/rupa/z)].

Comment: Wow that's interesting. I'd vote up your reply if I could :)